# MongoDB stores incorrect DOB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, date

I am using Java Date to store DOB of Person and saving the details in MongoDB. However in MongoDB the Date is one day less than the actual DOB .
For Example 
In Java the DOB is : Mon May 20 00:00:00 IST 2019
In MongoDB stored value is : 2019-05-19T18:30:00.000+0000

Observe that the DOB in MongoDB one day less.
What could be the reason for the date mismatch ?

Both MongoDB and Java Application(SpringBoot Application) is Running on the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

India Standard Time (IST) is 5:30 hours ahead of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Therefore 2019-05-19T18:30:00.000+0000 UTC + 5.30 == Mon May 20 00:00:00 IST 2019

So the value is just stored in UTC in MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the top of [Kayaman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58320402/1426227), as you are storing a date of birth, it makes sense to use a local date value (without time and without time-zone). The equivalent class for that in Java is [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html):

> `LocalDate` is an immutable date-time object that represents a date, often viewed as year-month-day. Other date fields, such as day-of-year, day-of-week and week-of-year, can also be accessed. For example, the value "2nd October 2007" can be stored in a `LocalDate`.
>
> This class does not store or represent a time or time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

If you need both date and time, then it makes sense to store that information in UTC. In Java, it can be represented with [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) or [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).